# Dropzone Rails 505 Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone-rails](https://github.com/ncuesta/dropzonejs-rails) to add [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to my Rails app. I'm using CarrierWave for image uploads which is working fine without Dropzone.

I'm getting an error when I drop an image onto my dropzone form. The form is located on the edit page of my "Canvas" model.

Form html

```
<%= form_for(@canvas, :html => { :class => 'dropzone', :id => 'awesomeDropzone' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Dropzone JS call

```
Dropzone.options.awesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "canvas[image]", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  clickable: false
};
```

Console error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/canvases/21/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

canvases_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @canvas = Canvas.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @canvas = Canvas.find(params[:id])

  if @canvas.update_attributes(update_params)
    redirect_to edit_canvas_path(@canvas)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

canvas.rb

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

[Full log data](https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/11272614)

Comment: Turn on debugging (`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`) and look at the actual error and stack trace.

Comment: How do I turn on debugging? What do I do with that line of code you wrote?

Comment: If you're running your rails application with `RAILS_ENV` set to development, this is the default, and you'll see an error and stack trace output. If you're running in a different environment (specifically, production), by default you won't see errors. You can either adjust the setting in the relevant `config/environments/____.rb` file or change the environment you're booting in. Since this is localhost, you probably just want to run in development mode.

Comment: You should have the full trace in your logs; by default, that's at `./log/#{environment}.log`.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the logs....I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error,

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template canvases/edit, application/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/colmtuite/dev/design_tool/app/views"
):
```

You don't have `edit` view for `canvases`. Make sure that you have `edit.html.erb` file in `app/views/canvases` folder.

**UPDATE**

Also, I noticed that the request is going for `Processing by CanvasesController#edit as JSON`,
NOTE the format is `JSON` and not `HTML`. If you have `edit.html.erb` file and you want to render that particular view, make sure that you don't specify format as 'JSON' while calling `edit` action so by default format would be considered as `HTML`.

Change your `update` action as below:

```
def update
  @canvas = Canvas.find(params[:id])

  if @canvas.update_attributes(update_params)
    redirect_to edit_canvas_path(@canvas, format: :html) ## Specify format as html
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, I have that file. That's the page my form is on.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm specifying any JSON. I'm not even sure what JSON is? The Dropzone docs says this "If the server returns JSON, it will be parsed for error messages as well". Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

*dropzone* using **JSON** format, not **HTML**, so
you can change controller to:

```
render nothing: true
```

or

```
render nothing: true, status: 200
```

Regards!